# AUTOMATIC TAGS in COMPONENTS OF

Tags: asn.1

Reading https://www.itu.int/rec/T-REC-X.680-201508-I, I was wondering how components inserted with COMPONENTS OF were tagged in AUTOMATIC TAGS context.

The topic 25.4 has an unequivocal note:

> The effect of this is that the application of automatic tags is
>   suppressed by tags textually present in the "ComponentTypeLists", but
>   not by tags present in the "Type" following COMPONENTS OF.

So, logic tells me that if some tags are found in the components of the COMPONENTS OF type, they won't be copied during the transformation.

Indeed, if I try this on http://asn1-playground.oss.com/ ...

```
ModuleA DEFINITIONS AUTOMATIC TAGS ::=

BEGIN

A ::= SEQUENCE {
    a   INTEGER,
    COMPONENTS OF B,
    b   INTEGER
}

B::= SEQUENCE  {
    c   REAL,
    d   [1] INTEGER,
    e   REAL
}

END
```

I get this ...

```
Encoding to the file 'data.ber' using BER encoding rule...
A SEQUENCE: tag = [UNIVERSAL 16] constructed; length = 17
  a INTEGER: tag = [0] primitive; length = 1
    1
  c REAL: tag = [1] primitive; length = 2
    "1"
  d INTEGER: tag = [2] primitive; length = 1
    1
  e REAL: tag = [3] primitive; length = 2
    "1"
  b INTEGER: tag = [4] primitive; length = 1
    1
```

My question is this: where in https://www.itu.int/rec/T-REC-X.680-201508-I is actually written that the tags of the COMPONENTS OF type are dropped in the transformation ?

I can only read that extensions and subtype constraints are dropped.

I can only see that, back in 2004, somebody seemed to get it wrong: http://lists.asn1.org/pipermail/asn1/2005-July/000285.html

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The standard states that when a module has automatic tags and a sequence et al is candidate for automatic tagging the compiler will add for each field a virtual context tag.

The standard also states that when a module has automatic tags it also means that it has implicit tags.

This implicit tagging is what make the compiler to skip the tag that you have gave to the "d" field.

So, to make it clear your, if we manually unroll components of and automatic tags then your example becomes.:

```
ModuleA DEFINITIONS AUTOMATIC TAGS ::=

BEGIN

A ::= SEQUENCE {
    a   [0]INTEGER,
    c   [1]REAL,
    d   [2][1] INTEGER,
    e   [3]REAL,
    b   [4]INTEGER
}

B::= SEQUENCE  {
    c   REAL,
    d   [1] INTEGER,
    e   REAL
}

END
```

So is not COMPONENTS OF that is dropping your context tag, but the implicit tagging of the module.

Comment: Yes this makes perfect sense. Thanks